# C# generics: how to simplify call of the specific type

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a code like this:

```
  if (args.ElementType == typeof(SomeFirstClassName))
  {
    args.Result = GetResult<SomeFirstClassName>(args);
  }
  else if (args.ElementType == typeof(SomeSecondClassName))
  {
    args.Result = GetResult<SomeSecondClassName>(args);
  }
```

How I can simplify this code, if I will have a many types?
For example, can I do something like below?

```
args.Result = this.GetResult<**args.ElementType**>(args);
```

I cannot put the variable Type (*args.ElementType*) to the <>. Is it limitation of C#?

Comment: what definition for `GetResult`? and what is `args`?

Comment: You can but you would need to use reflection.

Comment: I have corrected my answer, I didn't see the additional `ElementType`.

Answer (score 1):

You simplify this without reflection by using a dictionary which maps the type to the method to call.

Here's a sample program to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class SomeFirstClassName{}

    public class SomeSecondClassName{}

    public class Result {}

    public class Args
    {
        public Result Result;
        public Type   ElementType;
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, Func<Args, Result>> map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Args, Result>>();

        private void run()
        {
            init();

            var args1 = new Args {ElementType = typeof(SomeFirstClassName)};
            var args2 = new Args {ElementType = typeof(SomeSecondClassName)};

            test(args1); // Calls GetResult<T> for Demo.SomeFirstClassName.
            test(args2); // Calls GetResult<T> for Demo.SomeSecondClassName.
        }

        private void test(Args args)
        {
            args.Result = map[args.ElementType](args);
        }

        private void init()
        {
            map.Add(typeof(SomeFirstClassName),  GetResult<SomeFirstClassName>);
            map.Add(typeof(SomeSecondClassName), GetResult<SomeSecondClassName>);
        }

        public Result GetResult<T>(Args args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetResult<T>() called for T = " + typeof(T).FullName);
            return null;
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes the call site much simpler (`args.Result = map[args.ElementType](args);`) but you will still have to add an initialiser for each type to the `init()` method, as shown above.

However this does at least move all the type logic into a single method (`init()`) which I think is a cleaner and more maintainable design.

---

However, I can't help but think that there is going to be a much better object-oriented solution to what you're trying to achieve. But we'd need a lot more information about what it is you want to do (this looks like it might be an [`X-Y`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is to use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method). However, if you are looking for a non-reflection way of getting around this then you could pass in `ElementType` in as a parameter

```
GetResult<TElementType, TArgs>(TElementType elementType, TArgs args)
```

This would reduce your code to a single call i.e. `GetResult(args.ElementType, args)`. It's not *great* but it would give you what you want.

Comment: your call not working `args.ElementType` is Type not a variable

Comment: @Grundy not sure I understand your comment?

Comment: I mean when you call `GetResult(args.ElementType, args)` then `TElementType` will be `Type`